# Почему не работает mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql

Интересно как все работает в php и задался вопросом, с чего бы вдруг не заполняет таблицы запросом INSERT INTO?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `application` (`Date`,`Client_ID`,`Comments`,`Time`) VALUES('". $date ."','". $ids ."' ,'". $comment ."','". $time ."');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `clients` (`ID`,`SurName`,`Name`,`Patronymic`,`Phone`) VALUES('". $ids ."','". $surname ."','". $name ."' ,'". $patronymic ."','". $tel ."');";

if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)===TRUE){
    echo '1';
}
```

Comment: потому что надо сначала документацию к методу прочитать

Comment: но если у вас даже в первую таблицу данные не вставляются, то надо вывести ошибки.

Comment: @teran, я прочитал и сделал точно также. Все запросы рабочие , проверялись по отдельности. mysqli_error не показывает код ошибки... Единственная догадка, это добавление в не одинаковые таблицы